# MySQL: Disqualifying rows from selection when a column has a value over a threshold

Tags: mysql, max, distinct

I have one large table (about 9 million rows) called Person. It has several columns, one column is a Score from 1-10. Another column is a Name. I would like a query to return a DISTINCT list of the Names that do not have a Score >= 7 anywhere in the table.

I can get a list of DISTINCT Names, that is easy:

```
SELECT DISTINCT Name FROM Person
```

and I can get Scores less than 7:

```
WHERE Score < 7
```

but this just returns a large number of rows where the score for the Name is less than 7.  There are many other rows in the table where the Score for a Nameis greater than 7 -- they are not returned, but the exist in the table. I want to list the Name only when NO score of 7 or greater exists anywhere in the table. IN other words, I am looking for a table-wide perspective for the SELECT, not a row-by-row perspective.

I have tried to use the MAX function, the EXISTS function, a temporary table, and combinations. I thought I could use GREATEST(Score) for each Name, but that also didn't work. I need something like a "For Each" loop to tell MySQL:

```
 FOR EACH (Unique) Name in Person
   Check the Score for that Name in all rows. 
   If any row is greater than or equal to 7 mark that Name as disqualified and 
   move to the next name. Repeat with the new name. 
   UNTIL all Names are tested. 
   RETURN any DISTINCT Names still qualified.
```

I have a funny feeling I am thinking about this all wrong, and overcomplicating it, but right now nothing more is coming to me. Help?

Answer (score 2):

One option uses conditional aggregation:

```
SELECT Name
FROM Person
GROUP BY Name
HAVING SUM(CASE WHEN Score >= 7 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) = 0;
```

You could also use `EXISTS`:

```
SELECT DISTINCT p1.Name
FROM Person p1
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM Person p2 WHERE p2.Score >= 7 p1.Name = p2.Name);
```

Comment: Thanks! "Conditional Aggregation" is a nice short way of saying what I was trying to explain.  That solution seems to at least get me approximately the correct number of results (I need to check more deeply.)  In the EXISTS example, though, I don't understand where the p2 comes from.  I assume p1 is the shorthand label for the Person table, but where does p2 come from?  Is the (SELECT 1 FROM Person p2...) phrase creating a sort of temporary table named p2?

Comment: Do you not see `Person p2` in the exists subquery?  Note that SQL is not a "sort of" technology.  If my result set is not what you expect then either you stated you requirements wrongly or I have misinterpreted what you said.

Comment: Of course I do see it, and that is why I am asking about it. But perhaps I asked wrong -- my question is "What purpose does the p2 declaration serve in your answer? Can you explain what the parenthesized SELECT statement does in plain English?"

Comment: Sure.  For each name in `Person` it checks whether there exists at least one record with the _same_ name for which the score is also >= 7.  If found, then that name is disqualified.